# how to use ng-bind-html value in anchor tag

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am linking ng-bind-HTML value to anchor tag from API as follows

```
<div ng-bind-html="pdfdownload helpItems.items['devepragaticms:pdf1'].link.url">
<a href="{{pdfdownload}}" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

but I am not able to get the file to download.

API is as follow:

[image: API generated for PDF file upload]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the 'angular-sanitize' dependency first, use bower or something else, then you can directly use ng-bind-html="xxx" in the template.

Please refer to https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize for detail.